# How to use jQuery.validity properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Yesterday, I started here asking a question about my own project, and when I saw how helpful the people are and how fast they answered, I was really happy. My father is making a project by himself, and he asked me to write a question here for him because of English knowledge matters.

Well, he is trying to validate a form using jQuery.validity ( http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com ), but his function of validation is not working. Here is his code: http://pastebin.com/uvXRTZsE

I'm sorry for not pasting it here, but after several tries, parts of the code were missing when pasting them here.

Comment: Try pasting the code in anyway and save. We can edit it for you, you're probably just not yet understanding how the code formatting system works.

Comment: Im ashamed of myself but each time I try it i get the following:
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I followed instructions, left 4 spaces, but still. Im sorry :s

Comment: id's have to be unique. There are four elements with the id 'organizacion'

Comment: but in that case I still get an error because what I want is to make sure the user has ticked one of the options, if I change the id it checks only if one of them is ticked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main problems that I see here:

**The id's on the input elements are not unique.**

As per the spec, an id on any element on a page must be unique. In other words, you shouldn't use id="organizacion" 4 times like you are. This may or may not affect the ability for scripts to locate your elements, considering they'll likely stop at the first one, being implemented with the knowledge and understanding that id's must be unique.

**Validity doesn't have any documentation supporting radio button validation.**

I don't see any text fields in your HTML, and I don't see any documentation in Validity in regards to radio buttons. Thus, what you're trying to accomplish may not be possible with Validity.

As a final point, radio buttons are designed so that, in a group, one must always be selected. It's not possible to de-select a radio button. Thus, you should be sure that a default radio button is selected.

This may of course eliminate the need to make this a required field, since by default an option is already selected.

Comment: As a guy told me yesterday. Best answer is the simplest one. Lots of thanks for your help. Seems that I was focused on using validity that I didnt realice about making one already selected.

Thankyou

Comment: There is a documentation for checking radio buttons. But it's "hidden"  as an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/validity/issues/detail?id=1)

Comment: @john_doe - I could see use for this if the question-asker wanted to add a default radio button called "none" and then validate that some other option must be selected in order to submit! Good find!

Answer (score 0):

Validity doesn't have any documentation supporting radio button validation but you can do:

```
$('#form').validity(function(){
    $('#my_input_radio').assert($('#my_input_radio').is('checked'), 'Please check a radio');
});
```